# How to dynamically center an image within an anchor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor element wrapped around an image, providing the usual link functionality as well as an expand on click functionality. If Javascript is enabled, the anchor element is supposed to occupy the entire screen with a white background and the image is supposed to be at the centre **upon clicking**. Currently the image is at the top left corner of the screen. I have tried a similar example in "[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376466/centering-an-image-within-an-anchor-element)", but it doesn't seem to work for my case. Below is my code:

```
<script>
function resize(me) {
 $(me).toggleClass('pop_up');
 $(me).find('img').toggleClass('resize');
}
</script>

<div>
 <a href='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/361px-Flower_poster_2.jpg' onclick='resize(this); return false;'>
  <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/361px-Flower_poster_2.jpg'/>
 </a>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
img {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}

.resize {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
}

.pop_up {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}
```

Sorry, I think many of you misread my question. It is centering the image after clicking, not before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with css. Like this:

```
img {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
a{
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tBCcd/

**UPDATED**

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tBCcd/1/

Comment: I want to center the image upon clicking, not before that.

Comment: is your <a> tag height is fixed ?

Comment: The <a> tag height is auto before click and 100% of browser window upon clicking.

Comment: Err.. My intention is to have a thumbnail which upon clicking, expand to its actual dimension and position itself at the centre of a webpage, covering the page itself with the white background from the anchor element. Similar like opening the link, but with the image at center.

Comment: Hey sandeep, thanks for helping me. I am sorry but it is quite different from my original implementation. I need the position fixed because the thumbnail is more than one screen height below the top of the page. This click is supposed to act like a popup, except that it is on the same window.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, here the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3ArU/8/)

HTML part

```
 <div>
  <a href='http://akajake.com/web/images/rss-feed-icon.gif' onClick="javascript: console.log($(this).toggleClass('centered')); return false;">
     <img src='http://akajake.com/web/images/rss-feed-icon.gif'/>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS part

```
img.centered {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
a.centered {
   display:block;
   width:300px;
   border:1px solid black;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to center it, there's a lot of plugins that do it. Like this one: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/autocenter

Comment: Can it be done without plugins? I am looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: Anyway, the benefit of jQuery is the general cross browser abstractions of common javascript usages.

Comment: It can't be done without plugins with only css. You will have to use tables and it is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Here the [CSS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/f3ArU/4/).

Simply by setting margin-left and margin-right to `auto`:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

img.displayed {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
}
...
<img class="displayed" src="..." alt="...">
```

Comment: How about the vertical dimension?

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked nice as the following:

```
a img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
}
```

Tried on all major browsers: moz, chrome, ie8, safari